# Undefined method 'link_to_add\remove' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ive been doing some research and I can't seem to find what Im doing wrong.

I have installed simple_form and nested_form gems but when I use either link_to_add or remove I get the same error.

Heres the code

/fields.html.erb

```
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
    <%= f.input :nombre_cliente, :label => 'Nombre del cliente:', :as => :string %>
    <%= f.input :mail_cliente, :label => 'E-mail del cliente:', :as => :string %>
    <%= f.input :empresa_cliente, :label => 'Empresa:', :as => :string %>
    <%= f.input :confirmada, :label => 'Ha sido confirmada por el cliente.' %>
    <%= f.input :confirmacion_cliente, :label => 'Fecha de confirmacion por el cliente:', :as => :date %>
    <b>something here</b>
    </br></br>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :producto_de_cotizacion do |productos| %>
     <%= productos.input :nombre %>
     <%= productos.input :descripcion %>
     <%= productos.input :precio%>
     <%= productos.link_to_remove("Eliminar producto") %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.link_to_add "Agregar producto", :producto_de_cotizacion %>
```

Some of it is in spanish but I think its understandable

Here is the actual error Im getting:

> undefined method `link_to_remove' for < SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x9ccf37c>

That is the entirety of _fields.html.erb, but its being called by the new.html.erb and the edit.html.erb files which are basically identical, Ill post the edit file:

```
<h1>Agregar Cotizacion</h1>
<div id='admin_view'>
  <%= simple_form_for @cotizacion, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= render "fields", :f => f %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Actualizar Cotizacion' %>
      <% end%>
</div>
```

After changing it to simple_nested_form I get a new error:

```
undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

and heres the stack

```
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
/home/peanut/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/nested_form-57f32788f195/lib/nested_form/builder_mixin.rb:23:in `block in link_to_add'
/home/peanut/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/nested_form-57f32788f195/lib/nested_form/view_helper.rb:37:in `call'
/home/peanut/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/nested_form-57f32788f195/lib/nested_form/view_helper.rb:37:in `block in after_nested_form_callbacks'
/home/peanut/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/nested_form-57f32788f195/lib/nested_form/view_helper.rb:36:in `map'
/home/peanut/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/nested_form-57f32788f195/lib/nested_form/view_helper.rb:36:in `after_nested_form_callbacks'
/home/peanut/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bundler/gems/nested_form-57f32788f195/lib/nested_form/view_helper.rb:13:in `simple_nested_form_for'
app/views/cotizacions/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_cotizacions_edit_html_erb__855809706_86735240_354753338'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:135:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:54:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/template.rb:127:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:59:in `block in _render_template'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:56:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_view/render/rendering.rb:26:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:115:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:47:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:55:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:102:in `render_to_string'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:93:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/home/peanut/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:78:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:15:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
meta-tags (1.2.4) lib/meta_tags/controller_helper.rb:28:in `render_with_meta_tags'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:14:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:451:in `_run__761686272__process_action__750077467__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `block in call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `block in recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:89:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
warden (0.10.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (0.10.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (0.10.7) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `block in call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:106:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `block in call'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
/home/peanut/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/home/peanut/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/home/peanut/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Please post the actual error you are getting :)

Comment: Also, is that the entirety of fields.html.erb? As well, can you post where you are calling this partial from and what that code looks like?

Comment: Thanks, edited to add what you asked for.

Answer (score 11):

*Use `:locals => { :f => f }`*

**EDIT:** Changing my answer.

I just realized you are using:

```
simple_form_for
```

Change that to

```
simple_nested_form_for
```

This allows you to use the `nested_form` options (`link_to_add`, `link_to_remove`, etc).

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and got this error "undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0xab792b0>:0xab7834c>"

Comment: The form works fine if I remove the link_to_add and remove calls, so I think f is not the issue here :(

Comment: Re-read my answer, I just realized what was happening I believe.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to solve the issue with link_to_remove but the link_to_add gives me "undefined method 'klass' for nil:NilClass". Am I calling it wrong?

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace to your question edit to see what the whole error looks like

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the new.html.erb and edit.html.erb to look like this:

```
    <h1>Agregar Cotizacion</h1>
<div id='admin_view'>
  <%= simple_nested_form_for @cotizacion, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Agregar Cotizacion' %>
      <% end%>
</div>
```

And I added this to the routes.rb file

```
resources :cotizacions do
resources :producto_de_cotizacions
end
resources :producto_de_cotizacions
```

Im not exactly sure how but this fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for your help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have this error, solved by restarting server and adding this code to model:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```